# MediaPlayer class's stop method

Tags: android, audio

I'm developing an android application using Mediaplayer class that plays a song using a url.
if I call the stop method while the song is playing. it stopped. but, when i try to start it again using this code. it causes (1,-1004) error.

```
    mp.prepare();
    mp.start();
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: A -1004 error usually indicates that access is denied. Is this a web streaming audio or just like an actual MP3 file?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to implement onpreparedlistener and then call start from within that callback.

You're trying to play before it has finished buffering the media.

Comment: Isn't that what `prepareAsync` is for? That one will call the listener, the normal one doesnt.

Comment: Oops sorry. You are correct. I think you may have to call prepare again according to the diagram here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html